# Customizing the form for a field in the content edit form

Tags: entities

I have configured a taxonomy as field of a content type, but I want to replace the checkbox label (work with iphone) with the image field of that taxonomy. (See the screenshot.)

[image: screenshot]

I only know to alter node.pages.inc at row 290 by adding the following code.

```
$form['product_label'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => 'Checkboxes Title',
    '#title_display' => 'before',
    '#default_value' => array(0,2),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => 'option one',
      1 => 'option two',
      2 => 'option three', 
    ), 
    '#theme' => 'testmodule_checkboxes',
  );
```

product_label is the checkbox name. The above code is to override the current checkbox field.

I think this not the best way. Can anyone provide any direction? What module can do it?

Here is the dump of the checkbox field of the form.

```
array(6) { ["#type"]=> string(9) "container" ["#attributes"]=> array(1) { ["class"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(34) "field-type-taxonomy-term-reference" [1]=> string(22) "field-name-field-icon1" [2]=> string(28) "field-widget-options-buttons" } } ["#weight"]=> string(1) "2" ["#tree"]=> bool(true) ["#language"]=> string(3) "und" ["und"]=> array(18) { ["#entity"]=> object(stdClass)#91 (12) { ["uid"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(5) "admin" ["type"]=> string(7) "product" ["language"]=> string(3) "und" ["title"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(0) ["promote"]=> int(0) ["sticky"]=> int(0) ["created"]=> int(1344929691) ["revision"]=> bool(false) ["comment"]=> string(1) "1" ["menu"]=> array(12) { ["link_title"]=> string(0) "" ["mlid"]=> int(0) ["plid"]=> int(0) ["menu_name"]=> string(9) "main-menu" ["weight"]=> int(0) ["options"]=> array(0) { } ["module"]=> string(4) "menu" ["expanded"]=> int(0) ["hidden"]=> int(0) ["has_children"]=> int(0) ["customized"]=> int(0) ["parent_depth_limit"]=> int(8) } } ["#entity_type"]=> string(4) "node" ["#bundle"]=> string(7) "product" ["#field_name"]=> string(11) "field_icon1" ["#language"]=> string(3) "und" ["#field_parents"]=> array(0) { } ["#columns"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "tid" } ["#title"]=> string(4) "icon" ["#description"]=> string(0) "" ["#required"]=> bool(false) ["#delta"]=> int(0) ["#type"]=> string(10) "checkboxes" ["#default_value"]=> array(0) { } ["#options"]=> array(1) { [14]=> string(16) "Work with iphone" } ["#value_key"]=> string(3) "tid" ["#element_validate"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(29) "options_field_widget_validate" } ["#properties"]=> array(4) { ["filter_xss"]=> bool(true) ["strip_tags"]=> bool(false) ["empty_option"]=> bool(false) ["optgroups"]=> bool(false) } ["#after_build"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(30) "field_form_element_after_build" } } }
```

The problem is that I can't find the image (filename) which is a custom field of the taxonomy. I want to replace "work with iphone" with the uploaded image. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

first of all use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to alter any form. so in your custom module something like this

```
function CUSTOMMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
   if ($form_id == 'FORM_ID'){
     --
   }
```

Comment: but the form is in node/add/product, so i need to create custom module?

Comment: drupal rule #1 : never ever modify core files, drupal always give a way to override , so you have to create a module

Comment: i've added 

function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dsm($form_id);  // print form ID to messages
  dsm($form);  // pretty print array using Krumo to messages
}

but it doesn't run

Comment: your custom module name is custom , right? (according to code you used), also make sure its enabled, .. i cant find any error on ur code! you installed devel module right? if not use `print_r($form_id) instead of dsm();`

Comment: i even use echo "abc", it can't run

Comment: the file name is "custom.module"

Comment: # custom module is enabled
# when i add a line echo $form_id in custom.module , there is an error Notice: Undefined variable: form_id in include_once() (line 3 of C:\xampp\htdocs\2010\d2\modules\custom\custom.module).

Comment: after i re-enabled the module, the code now can print something

Comment: drupal rule #2 - 2010\d2\modules\custom\custom.module ? 
assuming d2 is ur drupal folder, custom module should be here d2/sites/all/modules/custom/custom.module ,

Comment: taxonomy screenshot http://www.photouploads.com/images/drupalq.jpg